# Configure wireless interface for multiple locations

Tags: debian, network-interface, internet

I want to configure my `/etc/network/interfaces` to detect different access points and connect to them accordingly. This is the current state of this file:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto ra0
iface ra0 inet dhcp
 wpa-ssid MyNet
 wpa-psk 00d8f778e1e86be0961aa767564d7364ee44fcbd704e4e31ee6c4af0f855c32f
```

This successfully detects an ethernet connection and connects to MyNet when it is available. How do I configure it so it can detect multiple access points?

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic#Configure_laptops_for_multiple_locations) seems to be the answer, but I wasn't able to understand the instructions.

I have tried multiple GUIs (nm, wicd, etc.), but none of them seems to work on my laptop. Anyway, I prefer to do it via command line.

Comment: It is more simple than that link. I added an answer.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Sorry, I didn't mentioned it in my question but I already tried wpa_supplicant and it's not working in my laptop. Also, I am really puzzled by this configuration file and would like to know how to edit it :-)

Comment: wpa_supplicant is definitely working on your laptop, because it's the only Linux software that deals with encrypted WLAN. It's possible that you are running network manager (which uses wpa_supplicant), so you need to either disable network manager, or configure it instead of wpa_supplicant (because configuring for both won't work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to configure `/etc/network/interfaces` to work with multiple locations, you have to understand the difference between logical and physical interfaces. Physical interfaces correspond to the hardware devices that you have installed in your system and they are identified by a particular naming scheme (wlan0, wlan1, eth0, ra0, etc).

In your `/etc/network/interfaces`, you can specify only one configuration for each physical interface, so this is where logical interfaces come into play. You can have multiple logical interfaces for one physical interface. This is called mapping. To map a logical interface to a physical interface, you add this to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
mapping ra0 # map physical interface ra0...
    map home work # ...to 'home' and 'work' logical interfaces
```

Then, you write the configuration for each of these interfaces:

```
iface home inet dhcp # configuration stanza for 'home' logical interface
 wpa-ssid Home
 wpa-psk 00d8f778e1e86be0961aa767564d7364ee44fcbd704e4e31ee6c4af0f855c32f

iface work inet dhcp # configuration stanza for 'work' logical interface
 wpa-ssid Work
 wpa-psk 00d8f778e1e86be0961aa767564d7364ee44fcbd704e4e31ee6c4af0f855c32f
```

Of course, this is not going to work because the system doesn't know which interface to use, so we'll use `guessnet` to help the system to choose a configuration.

```
sudo apt-get install guessnet
```

Then, we use `guessnet` in the mapping stanza:

```
mapping ra0
        script /usr/sbin/guessnet-ifupdown # <-- We added this
        map home work
```

`Guessnet` acts by testing the networks according to some criteria (IP, ESSID, MAC addresses) and choosing the configuration that doesn't fail those tests. In the following example, if there is a network with ESSID 'Work' available, the interface `ra0` that we defined earlier, is going to connect to it and apply this configuration:

```
iface work inet dhcp 
 test wireless essid Work # We test if the ESSID of the network is 'Work'
 wpa-ssid Work
 wpa-psk 00d8f778e1e86be0961aa767564d7364ee44fcbd704e4e31ee6c4af0f855c32f
```

Answer (score 6):

To address multiple wifi configs/ssids, you would better work at the `wpa_supplicant` level.

Just leave your interface as:

```
auto ra0
iface ra0 inet dhcp
```

Install wpa_supplicant with:

```
apt get install wpasupplicant
```

You can define several locations in `wpa_supplicant.conf`, where the SSID determines which configuration will be used. As in:

```
network={
    ssid="ssid2"
    psk="ssid2 PASSWORD"
}

network={
    ssid="ssid1"
    psk="ssid1 PASSWORD"
}
```

Restart the service each time you add a configuration for a new SSID.

When connection to an AP, depending on the SSID name, `wpa_supplicant` with automagically select the corresponding configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In our case we wanted to dedicate different wlan's to specific devices.  To do that we created a systemd template:

```ini
# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant\@.service 
[Unit]
Description=WPA supplicant for %i
Before=network.target
After=dbus.service
Wants=network.target
IgnoreOnIsolate=true

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant-%i -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-%i.conf -i%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then created the configs like so:

```
==> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <==
network={
    ssid="net0"
    psk="secretpass0"
}

==> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf <==
network={
    ssid="net1"
    psk="secretpass1"
}
```

and started them as follows:

```bash
systemctl enable --now wpa_supplicant@wlan0
systemctl enable --now wpa_supplicant@wlan1
```

**Caveat:**

Strangely, it seems to have ignored my service and run it under `dhcpcd`:

```
# ps ax|grep wpa

    653 ?        Ss     0:00 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf -iwlan1
    668 ?        Ss     0:00 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -iwlan0

# systemctl status 668
● dhcpcd.service - DHCP Client Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
             └─wait.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-07-08 21:16:25 BST; 1min 23s ago
       Docs: man:dhcpcd(8)
    Process: 545 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpcd -w -q (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 1993)
     Memory: 4.3M
        CPU: 775ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
             ├─653 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf -iwlan1
             ├─668 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -iwlan0
             └─701 /usr/sbin/dhcpcd -w -q
```

Maybe the Debian network stack or `dhclient` supports `wpa_supplicant-<device>.conf` files directly and does it automagically (note that my /etc/network/interfaces* files are empty). If that is the case then all you need is different configs for different devices...but anyway, this works for us.  Please comment if you find out why this is so.